# Getting short timezone abbreviation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have string representing datetime and time zone (IANA) on client side.

How do I get abbreviation for it (like EST/EDT)?

Comment: You could have a look at the source of `moment.js`. I think there is no JS native way to get the abbreviation.

Comment: Do you need every single timezone abbreviation? Without doing some sort of geolocation, I don't think it would be possible to differentiate between, for example, Whiskey, Cook, and Tahiti time zones, all of which share UTC - 10 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js).

Once you set it up (you'll need fresh version of IANA/Olson timezone database, see docs) you can use it to get abbreviation for given datetime and timezone:

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008', 'America/New_York');
var abbreviation = dt.getTimezoneAbbreviation();
```

... (`abbreviation` will be equal to `"EDT"`)